# What do the bulk of the pre-calculus questions in the mathematics (subject) GRE look like?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, gre

i am planning to take the subject test this year and have decent foundations in precalc, however, i would like to study it thoroughly again but i don't want to spend too much time on it and instead focus on calculus as it makes up half of the problems. for those who have taken the test before, what aspects of precalc should i focus on in my revision of it and what kinds of problems should i be routinely solving?

thanks!

Comment: The subject test is focused much (much) more on more advanced courses. Precalc will get you nowhere. Even calc alone won't get you a good grade. The exam is intended for upper level math majors. I'm curious about what you are studying that you would attempt this test.

Comment: Note also that the "calculus" portion is more than elementary calculus and includes advanced calc and beginning analysis. Also differential equations. Any precalc is included in the 50%. The "algebra" in the other half isn't elementary algebra but Abstract Algebra, such as Group Theory and beyond. I took the test long ago and was a strong math major close to graduation. For a surprising number of questions, I had no idea, even, of the terminology since the test is very broad; broader than most math programs. Broad enough that a math major might do well independent of details in their major.

Answer (score 3):

The most direct way to learn about the nature of the GRE mathematics subject test is to look at a [GRE practice test](https://web.archive.org/web/20240229002316/https://wmich.edu/mathclub/files/GR9768.pdf). You can then form your own opinion about what you will most need to study.